# regrading asymptotic curve

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

How can we check any curve $y=f(x)$ is asymptotic as we move $x$ tends to any point? (e,g., if we take as $x\to \infty$, $y=f(x)$ is asymptotic along $y$-axis, how can we prove this?)

I was following [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_curve#:~:text=An%20asymptotic%20direction%20is%20one,zero%20curvature%20at%20that%20point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_curve#:%7E:text=An%20asymptotic%20direction%20is%20one,zero%20curvature%20at%20that%20point).

But could not get any idea explicitly.

Can anyone please give me any references?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your example, as $x\to \infty$, your curve is moving away from the $y$-axis...if you meant $x$-axis, you could check whether $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$. More broadly, if you want to know whether $g(x)$ is an asymptote of $f(x)$ as $x\to \infty$, you can check if $\lim_{x\to \infty} [f(x)-g(x)] = 0$.

Comment: @AmaanM OK! Thanks for your comments. So, if $f(x)=e^{-x}$, as $x\to \infty$, $f(x)\to 0$. So, in this case $X$-axis is the asymptote. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.